# Difference in memory between two code fragments

Tags: javascript, java, memory

**Java Code sample 1:**

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outerList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for(i=0; i<5000; i++){  
    outerList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    for(j=0; j<5000; j++){
        outerList.get(i).add(1);
    }
}
```

**Java Code sample 2:**

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outerList_n = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> innerList_n = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(j=0; j<5000; j++){
    innerList_n.add(1);
}   
for(i=0; i<5000; i++){  
    outerList_n.add(innerList_n);
}
```

**Description**:

Code sample 1 creates a new arrayList everytime for adding to the outerlist, although every entry for the innerList in always 1.

Code sample 2 creates one array with the all entries as 1 and then adds it to the outerList in the for loop.

**Questions**:

1) Do they both have different memory footprints or same? 
I used jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.debug.ObjectSizeCalculator to calculate it and the following are the results:

Size of outerList: 514907072

Size of outerList_n: 130048

2) I do not understand why the above difference in memory. Isn't the data structure same in both cases?

3) Is this the same case in javascript? When I tried the respective codes for javascript for the above 2 scenarios, I got the same memory footprint in both cases.

**Javascript Code:**

```
function sizeof(object){

  // initialise the list of objects and size
  var objects = [object];
  var size    = 0;

  // loop over the objects
  for (var index = 0; index < objects.length; index ++){

    // determine the type of the object
    switch (typeof objects[index]){

      // the object is a boolean
      case 'boolean': size += 4; break;

      // the object is a number
      case 'number': size += 8; break;

      // the object is a string
      case 'string': size += 2 * objects[index].length; break;

      // the object is a generic object
      case 'object':

        // if the object is not an array, add the sizes of the keys
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(objects[index]) != '[object Array]'){
          for (var key in objects[index]) size += 2 * key.length;
        }

        // loop over the keys
        for (var key in objects[index]){    
          // determine whether the value has already been processed
          var processed = false;
          for (var search = 0; search < objects.length; search ++){
            if (objects[search] === objects[index][key]){
              processed = true;
              break;
            }
          }    
          // queue the value to be processed if appropriate
          if (!processed) objects.push(objects[index][key]);    
        }    
    }    
  }    
  // return the calculated size
  return size;    
}

// TWO SEPARATE FOR LOOPS
var start = new Date().getTime();
var i,j ;
var inner_arr1 = [];
var outer_arr1 = [];
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    inner_arr1.push("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
}
for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    outer_arr1.push(inner_arr1);
}
var end = new Date().getTime();
print("size of outer_arr1: "+sizeof(outer_arr1));
print("time of outer_arr1 (in ms): "+(end-start))


// NESTED FOR LOOPS
var start = new Date().getTime();
var outer_arr2 = [];
for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    var inner_arr2 = [];    
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        inner_arr2.push("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");   
    }
    outer_arr2.push(inner_arr1);    
}
var end = new Date().getTime();
print("size of outer_arr2: "+sizeof(outer_arr2));
print("time of outer_arr2 (in ms): "+(end-start))


/*
COMMAND:
jjs findingSize.js

OUTPUT:
size of outer_arr1: 52
time of outer_arr1 (in ms): 45
size of outer_arr2: 52
time of outer_arr2 (in ms): 58
*/
```

Comment: both r different , Code sample 1 will run for 25000 times and added 5000 list unnecessary

Comment: first sample will run 5000^2 times, whereas the second one will only run 10000 times

Comment: I am aware of the number of iterations. But the question here is about memory.

Comment: Hint: in the second case you can see two `new` operators. How many in the first one?

Answer (score 3):

> Do they both have different memory footprints or same?

Different. In the first case you are creating 5001 instances of ArrayList. In the second you are creating only two instance of ArrayList

> Isn't the data structure same in both cases?

The structure of data is the same in both cases - you have array of arrays. The only difference is that in the second case all your innner arrays are same - they share the common memory and when you change value in some row, all rows will be changed

Comment: So, when I do ArrayList.add(x), the x is not a copy but the original array itself?

Comment: Yes, in java classes are reference types. Each assignment copies reference, but not the array itself. Your assumption would be valid for C++ (of course if you don't store pointers to vectors), but not for java

Comment: I have edited the question to include my observation in javascript. Could you answer why the memory is same in javascript? Is it like C++?

Comment: Are you sure your sizeof function is correct? How can it return 52 if your array should contain 100 elements?

Comment: I ll check it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

1. *Code sample 1* : it will create 5000 *different* `Lists` filled with 5000 times the value 1, all saved in `outerList` : 5000+1 = 5001 different List
2. *Code sample 2* : `outerList` contains 5000 times the *same* list (filled with 5000 times values 1) : 1+1 = 2 different Lists

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the evaluation is correct. Your first code sample has an inner loop. This is exponentially more than the second sample.

To put it plainly, the 2nd sample will iterate the first loop 5000 times, then the second loop 5000 times.

The first example will iterate the innerloop 5000 times, for each loop of the outer loop (another 5000 times) so you get 5000*5000 iterations ofouterList.get(i).add(1).

I hope this answers your question.